# Positional parameter not readable inside the variable - bash script

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scripting, positional-parameter

I have a problem with the small script I am working on, can you please explain why is this not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$( linux command to list ldap users | grep "user: $1")
echo $var1
```

So, when I deploy my script ( ./mycript.sh $michael  ), it should use that value instead of $1 and provide the output via echo $variable1? In my case that is not working.

Can you please explain how should I configure positional parameter inside the variable?

I tried the this solution, but that did not help:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$( linux command to list ldap users | grep user: $1)
echo $var1
```

Comment: Well, `var1` is not `variable1`. `In my case that is not working.` Debug the script. Run the script with `set -x` and confirm your asumptions. `$michael ), it should use that value instead of $1` What value? Is `michael` variable set in the parent process? `I tried the this solution, but that did not help:` But what did it result in? Did you get a message from `grep` that there is no such file? Most probably, `$michael` variable is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, that was a typo, it is var1

Comment: What is the value of `$michael` in the invoking shell?  Perhaps you meant `./myscript.sh michael`

Comment: You guys saved my day! I used ./myscript.sh $michael    instead of using ./myscript.sh michael    that is why there was no output.   I used this command many times before, but today I got stuck and I thought that the problem is with the script, not with the actual input, thus $michael does not exist, but michael does and it is working now!

I can study further without having this in my mind, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke your script as `./mycript.sh $michael` and the variable `michael` is not set in the shell, they you are calling your script with no arguments.  Perhaps you meant `./myscript.h michael` to pass the literal string `michael` as the first argument.  A good way to protect against this sort of error in your script is to write:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$( linux command to list ldap users | grep "user: ${1:?}")
echo "$var1"
```

The `${1:?}` will expand to $1 if that parameter is non-empty.  If it is empty, you'll get an error message.

If you'd like the script to terminate if no values are found by `grep`, you might want:

```
var1=$( linux command to list ldap users | grep "user: ${1:?}") || exit
```

But it's probably easier/better to actually validate the arguments and print an error message.  (Personally, I find the error message from `${:?}` constructs to bit less than ideal.)  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# -lt 1; then echo 'Missing arguments' >&2; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: You are right on the spot! Thank you very much you saved my day!